# Is it possible to export both an animated object and camera from Maya to Blender together?

Tags: animation, camera

Is it possible to export both an animated object and camera from Maya to Blender together? .mmd can export the object and collada can do the camera. Is there anything that can export both?

Comment: There's an .fbx importer for Blender, I doubt it's fully functional but worth a try.

Comment: I haven't had much luck with the .fbx importer so far but it would be worth a try to test it again. Thanks!

Comment: There has been a lot of work put into the .fbx exporter recently but so far as I know, not the importer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, the fbx importer isn't up to scratch yet. Your best bet is to keep everything in collada and bake your camera animation to a cube within maya first. Pain in the ass, but it always seems to be a struggle to get things between softwares, not just blender.